# What is the time before an alarm is given after a fire sensor perceives a fire?

Tags: aircraft-systems, fire, electrical-system

I've got a very specific question:

When a fire sensor perceives a fire, does it wait **20 or 60 seconds** before giving the alarm?

Comment: This may well be the _most_ specific question we have at Aviation!

Comment: FreeMan thanks for editing, sometimes I forgot the basic grammar...!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fire sensor's time to give the alarm is customizable depending upon the fire safety alarm being used. Two widely used types of continuous-loop systems are the thermistor type detectors, such as the Kidde and the Fenwal systems, and the pneumatic pressure detector, such as the Lingberg system. (Lindberg system is also known as Systron-Donner and, more recently, Meggitt Safety Systems.). A typical delay of **10 Seconds** is quite common. Here is the [Source](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/amt_airframe_handbook/media/ama_Ch17.pdf) for your further reading